# Send email on case creation by record type

Tags: email, email-template, case

We're using web-to-case to create cases. Different types of customers can create different types of cases, which we manage via Record Type on the Case object.
On case creation we would like the customers to get a confirmation email. Currently all customers are receiving the same email template. I do not know what process is sending this email, but I was able to find the template in question (I inherited this org...).

1. How do I turn off this notification?
2. How do I set up new notifications, so that each record type sends a different email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this with **Auto-Response rules**:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_auto-response_rules.htm

*Setup --> Case Auto-Response Rules*

You can check here to see if you have any existing rules. You can create a new rule and then rule entries. The entries act in an order and when the incoming case comes in it goes through these until it finds a match. When it does, it uses whatever you set as the Sent from category and template to send an email response for that case. You should be able to have several entries with specific templates for specific record types.

[image]

If you do not have any auto-response rules, then your "Web-to-Case" settings will contain the info in "**Default Response Template**". This would be what sends out if you have no Auto-response rules set up.

*Setup --> Web-to-Case*

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setting_up_web-to-case.htm&type=5

[image]